# How to keep Delphi App IDE target folder in track with installer default between 32 and 64-bit

Tags: delphi, 32bit-64bit, inno-setup

It's easiest when developing in the IDE to work with a Application target folder in the default location into which it will be installed e.g:

```
"c:\Program Files\MyAppFolder"
```

As a result, I have "c:\Program Files\MyAppFolder" coded into the Delphi project's 'Output directory' and I can prepare for development by running my installer (Innosetup) which populates that folder with supporting data files etc.

Now I'm moving between Windows7 64 and Windows 7 32 and my installer wants to put it's (32-bit) app into "c:\Program Files (x86)", so I need to point my IDE output at:

```
"c:\Program Files (86)\MyAppFolder"
```

This would be a change required in each project. Is there a predefined variable that I can use or some other method that would allow me to move between platforms with a 32-bit app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It's easiest when developing in the IDE to work with a Application target folder in the default location into which it will be installed e.g

Your application is supposed to work wherever the user installs it, and you obviously know that since you call the location "the default location". Since the app should work wherever you install it, it shouldn't matter where you're developing it.

Your `Program Files` choice is bad for a number of reasons:

- If you make the mistake of hard-coding a path in your application, you'll only learn about it when a client installs the application somewhere else.
- Doing your development in the Program Files folder requires you to work with UAC disabled: your client's are going to have UAC enabled, so you're not actually working in an environment that looks like the environment where the app is going to be used.
- You can't test application's installer: since you already have files in the "default location".
- Program Files goes through two folder redirectors: The 64 bit virtualization that makes 32 bit application read from `Program Files x86` when they say `Program Files` and the UAC virtualization that redirects write access to `Program Files` folders to folders in one's UserData directory.

It's my honest opinion that it's better to develop into an other directory, outside the `Program Files` minefield. For my own development I'm taking this to the next level: The same applications is developed in different folders on different computers. Example: I've got my app checked out in `C:\Appname`, my colleague has it in `D:\SomeFolder\AppName`

Comment: +1, very good answer. But I believe it should say "through" instead of "throw" in the last item, shouldn't it?

Comment: @mghie, thanks for pointing that out; @Ken, thanks for fixing it! I can learn a new programming language in an afternoon, but I keep making those silly mistakes after 15+ years of learning English. Funny thing this brain of ours...

Comment: Accepted because it's such a crisp answer and generally useful, I also take your point about the UAC redirector. But my general point still stands, that I need to have the installer dump the data files into the same location as I'm developing in. I like to force my customer to an installation location default for simplicity - they dont mind - so I guess I focussed on using that location. I will look a 'development' location as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use environment variables when specifying paths in Delphi.

Set output directory to `$(ProgramFiles)\MyAppFolder`.

`$(ProgramFiles)` in Win64 points to `Program Files x(86)` for 32-bit applications. Delphi is 32-bit so that will work for you.

Comment: Yes, I know, but on W64 I need to point at "c:\program files (x86)" and you cannot put the standard pre-defined variable 'ProgramFiles(x86)' into $().

Comment: @Brian Frost - updated answer. I use 64-bit Win-7 and I have tested this.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't work for me because I have UAC enabled. I'd just stick it somewhere outside the program files folders.